# Выборка из таблиц со связью многие ко многим

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Нужно сделать выборку товаров (поле `id` и `name` в таблице `goods`) по номеру заказа (поле `id` в таблице `orders`). Связь реализовал через доп. таблицу `orders_goods`.

Сделана бд на `phpmyadmin`, вообще возможно такую выгрузку реализовать и как?

[image: таблица связей]

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT orders.id, goods.name FROM orders INNER JOIN (goods INNER JOIN orders_goods ON goods.id = orders_goods.id_good) ON orders.id = orders_goods.id_order
```

Кажется нашел решение.